# Add accessibility to pdf created with Quartz2d in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, accessibility

I am using Quartz 2d to create pdf files in an iOS app, based on [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) Wenderlich tutorial.  However, when the PDF is displayed to the user (Using QLPreview), Voice Over reads the PDF in a very non-intuitive order.  Is there a way to modify the PDF when being created to change the order Voice Over reads the data, and to add meta-data to images so they are properly read?  Thanks for any advice or help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: it is not possible. Quartz is just a drawing engine and not a dedicated PDF library.
You should try to write the text on the page in the order you want it to be read, it might help. I assume (I'm not sure) Voice Over reads the text in the order it appears in the page content when Accessibility is not present.